# Symfony2 form validation

Tags: bind, symfony

In my entity, I have a field like :

```
/**
 * @var decimal $Size
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Size", type="decimal", scale="2")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Type(type="numeric")
 */
private $Size;
```

But when I type a string, like 'foo' in the creation form, the function bindRequest throws :

```
Expected argument of type "numeric", "boolean" given
500 Internal Server Error - UnexpectedTypeException
```

The controller code is :

```
$request = $this->get('request');
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
{           
     $form->bindRequest($request);   
     if ($form->isValid())
     {
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
         $em->persist($support);
         $em->flush();

         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('mediatheque_support_' . $shortcut . '_list'));
      }
 }
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there isn't mistake elsewhere? I tried the very same code and it works just okay. Aren't you manipulating POST data on some other place?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that isn't the expected behavior? You're Asserting a type "numeric" and providing a string "foo"... the error message is a little misleading however saying "boolean" provided